# Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found | Mongo and Laravel

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5

I've just started Mongo using Laravel and finding an issue for the connection, "Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found". Following is my composer.json snippet.

```
"require": {
  "php": ">=5.5.9",
  "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.2.*",
  "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2",
  "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.0.0"
}
```

The extension is enabled in php.in for mongodb.so
Moreover, the mongoDB is up and running via the mongo clint, RoboMongo.

This is how I am creating the instance for mongoDB, mongoDB is included at the top of the file by 'use'.

```
$mongoObj = new MongoDB\Client($host, ['username' => $username, 'password' => $password]);
```

I've seen many links and nothing worked for me. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you updated `config/database.php > connections > mongoDb` ?

Comment: @Phantom, there is no entry for mongo in the 'connections' array. I'm getting the credentials from the .env file.

Comment: Actually I have got the same error when I did...I was using `jenssegers mongodb` library, then I install dll extension for php, added driver in database.php and it was working after that.

Comment: @Phantom, Alright.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check in your code a link to **'vendor/autoload.php'**. Somewhere in your code you shall have the following:

```
  $DB_CONNECTION_STRING="mongodb://YourCredentials";
  require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
```